# Visiting Croatia while in possession of a Swiss permit 'L'

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland, croatia

I hold a passport that requires me to have a visa to visit pretty much any country. However, as I am temporarily in Switzerland for 6 months, I have been given the Swiss 'L' permit that is valid until the end of October.

Although I need a visa, by right, to visit Croatia, I understand that Croatia has certain waivers in which visa nationals in possession of a multiple-entry Schengen visa or a valid Schengen residence permit can be allowed entry.

Does that mean I will be allowed to enter Croatia with my passport & my Swiss L permit if I were to visit in July? It would still be 90 days before the expiry of the Swiss permit.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=hr&SUBSECTION=VS&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit issued by Bulgaria,
>     Cyprus, Romania or a **Schengen Member State** for
>     a maximum stay of 90 days

So yes, you can visit Croatia without a visa - present your passport and residence permit at the border.